# How to update User Attributes in Azure AD B2C from ASP.NET Core?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

What is the best way to programmatically change the value of an Azure AD B2C custom attribute without using user flows. Should Azure AD Graph be used or the new Microsoft Graph? I was not able to find good documentation for doing this.

Comment: Hi, is there any update on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For Azure AD B2C custom attribute, you should use Azure AD Graph.

The custom attribute is shown in AAD Graph like this format: `extension_{appId}_{customAttribute}`.

So firstly you need to get the appID for it. You can use the applications endpoint with a filter to get the application ID: `GET https://graph.windows.net/myorganization//applications?api-version=1.6&$filter=startswith(displayName, 'b2c-extensions-app')`.

You can get the appID of the extension app. And now you know what the custom attribute name is: `extension_{appId}_{customAttribute}`.

Then you could call this endpoint to update the custom attribute.

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/userObjectId?api-version=1.6
{
    "extension_{appId}_{customAttribute}": "value"
}
```